# Why is the 'file transfer' button greyed out on TightVNC

Tags: raspbian, vnc

I have a tightVNC server running on rasbian on the raspberry Pi and I have a vnc viewer running on windows 7, 64 bit.

I wish to easily copy a file from the pi to my PC, but the 'Transfer Files' option on the toolbar on the viewer is disabled. I wonder why that is.

Comment: which version is used on the raspberry and on windows ?

Comment: hi @woliverajr, despite searching everywhere I cant figure out how you find out the version (and there is no menu > help > version option). But I installed it 2 weeks ago so it must be very new.

Comment: @woliveirajr Please don't suggest other sites without explaining how migrating questions works. Inexperienced users are often cross-posting the same question to multiple sites, which we consider abusive behavior. Also, please take a few minutes to [read this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/) – while I'm sure you're well meaning, it can be interpreted quite differently or have unpleasant effects.

Comment: Note: this was migrated to Rpi.SE at the request of the original asker.

Answer (score 3):

Not all VNC servers support file transfer, specifically the original realVNC server used on debian and the raspberrypi does not. The tightVNC file transfer extension is not well supported on anything but windows.

Answer (score 0):

Not all VNC viewers support file transfer, as it's not part of the original protocol. [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) does, so try that on your Windows machine.